# Sublime Text 2: name of the scope selector for Objective-C

Tags: code-snippets, sublimetext2

I am trying to create an Objective-C snippet in Sublime Text 2. I want to define the scope for the snippet so that the snippet is available in all Objective-C files.

But I just cannot find the scope selector for Objective-C. Here is my snippet...

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>objdid</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.html</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

I tried the scopes like `.m`, `.h`, `.Objective-C`, `.objective-c` but nothing worked. Saving the snippet like above makes the snippet to popup in all the files be it `.txt` or anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the `Objective-C.tmLanguage` file, you will see a key named `scopeName` with the value `source.objc`. Try that for scope.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Joachim's answer, I'd recommend a package called **Scope Hunter** which allows you to find the scope under your cursor at any time very quickly. Not only does it let you find the scope in a new language, but it also gives you a lot of granularity.

For example, typing the following in a new, plain text file:

```
* This is a bulleted item
```

has the scope:

```
Scope: text.plain meta.bullet-point.star.text
```

You get a very fine degree of granularity, which can often be useful when debugging snippets or defining a very precise snippet. For example, if you wanted a snippet that worked only in a Markdown list, then you could quickly find the exact scope for a Markdown list.

Very useful for finding new scopes.

You can download Scope Hunter from [**Github**](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter) or from **Package Control**.